# Where can DEM data for all of British Columbia be found?

Tags: dem, image-mosaic, canada

Is there a website or server from which a DEM covering all of BC can be downloaded - preferably at 1:50K scale?

[GeoBase](http://www.geobase.ca/) has tiles for 1:50K and 1:250K, but they do not provide it as a mosaic. It's not very time efficient to download 1000+ tiles and mosaic them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geobase would have been my first suggestion but aside from the way the tiles are separated to relatively small areas, I have personally had many issues with the data itself. [See our own wiki for more details.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1795/where-can-i-download-1-arc-second-elevation-data-for-canada-other-than-geobase)

If I remember correctly then 1 arc-seconds (about 30m resolution) (SRTM1) coverage only includes continental US in and parts of Canada but does not include all of BC.  3 arc-seconds (90m resolution) (SRTIM3) does include all of BC.  Some provinces have their own data warehouses. In Ontario it's LIO - Land Information Ontario from which users can obtain 20m resolution DEM for the entire province up to the 51st parallel, 10m resolution for Southern Ontario.  I remember purchasing data for BC in the past but I don't think government spatial data in BC is free.  You can purchase 25m resolution (USGS DEM standard) [here](http://archive.ilmb.gov.bc.ca/crgb/products/imagery/gridded.htm).

Alternatively you can download all available SRTM1 and 3 data directly from [USGS](http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/North_America/)

I found downloading SRTM3 from USGS and mosaicing all of the province of Ontario wasn't as much work as I anticipated but it still takes a while to download all the individual files.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a recipe for using [{bcmaps}](https://github.com/bcgov/bcmaps) and Jeffrey Hollister's excellent [{elevatr}](https://github.com/jhollist/elevatr) package that I've had some success with in 2022. It downloads a ~50m resolution DEM for a bounding box surrounding all of BC in WGS84 format. This method can be used to acquire even finer resolution products (I have gotten ~2m resolution for smaller extents), but the amount of computing power and memory required may be limiting if you're looking to do all of BC in one go for a really high resolution DEM.

I've also included steps to crop and mask the DEM to a hi-res boundary polygon for BC - otherwise the bounding box surrounding BC includes ocean bathymetry along the coast (a cool feature but this increases the file size a fair bit).

Cropping and masking operations on such a big file take substantial computing power and memory - if this is an issue for your device, then the jobs should probably be broken up appropriately and completed in increments.

NOTE: There is a bit of jumping between packages when it comes to the various functions below. This is something I'd really like to clean up in the future, but I was finding the various packages have their strengths.  I've also chosen to run the masking and cropping with `{tcltk}` progress bars (optional) so I could keep track of things. Please feel free to share any of your thoughtful critiques in the comments.

**1.Folder location and packages**

*Replace with your own path as necessary:*

```
here<-"C:/myfolder"

library("bcdata")
library("bcmaps")
library("elevatr")
library("raster")
library("rgdal")
library("sf")
library("stars")
library("tcltk")
library("terra")
library("tmap")
```

**2.Call BC boundary using `{bcmaps}`**

*Create an object `bc_boundary` by calling the hi-res version of a polygon for BC's boundary using `{bcmaps}` package.
Note that the default class is `sf` or simple features. I found that specifying `class ="sp"` or spatial made it easier
to work with in later operations below:*

```
bc_boundary <- bcmaps::bc_bound_hres(class = "sp")
```

**3.Get rough 50m resolution DEM of study area using `{elevatr}`**

*`{elevatr}` gathers elevation data for a rectangular bounding box around the study area. `{elevatr}` requires WGS84 format instead of NAD83 (the default output format from `{bcmaps}`). Reproject `bc_boundary` to WGS84 for compatibility with `{elevatr}`:*

```
bc_wgs84 <- spTransform(bc_boundary, CRS( "+init=epsg:4326" ) )
```

*Create an object that specifies projection for downloading DEM:*

```
prj_wgs84 <- "EPSG:4326"
```

*Download approximately 50m x 50m DEM at ~592 Mb file size using `{elevatr}`:*

```
elev50 <- get_elev_raster(locations = bc_wgs84,prj=prj_wgs84, z=10)
```

**4.Crop the DEM to the study area**

*`{elevatr}` gathers elevation data for a rectangular bounding box around the study area.*
*Crop the DEM (RUN TIME ~ 1 HOUR) to `bc_boundary` using `raster::crop` function within `{tcltk}` progress bar and `for` loop.*

*Set up conditions for separate progress bar window (progress bar is optional):*

```
n_iter <- 50 # Number of iterations
pb <- tkProgressBar(title = "Tk progress bar",      # window title
                    label = "Percentage completed", # window label
                    min = 0,      # minimum value of the bar
                    max = n_iter, # maximum value of the bar
                    initial = 0,  # initial value of the bar
                    width = 300)  # width of the window
```

*Progress bar `for` loop:*

```
for(i in 1:n_iter) {
  
  #(CAN BE RUN WITHOUT PROGRESS BAR FOR LOOP)
  #crop the DEM to the study area
  elev50_crop<-crop(elev50,bc_wgs84)
  
  pctg <- paste(round(i/n_iter *100, 0), "% completed")
  setTkProgressBar(pb, i, label = pctg)
}
```

*Close the connection after progress bar shows 100%:*

```
close(pb)
```

*Convert the cropped raster and `bc_boundary` polygons to formats compatible with `{terra}`.*

*`{terra}` is used for masking below as it was found to run better than `raster::mask`.*

*`{terra}` may be used for everything in the future rather than jumping back and forth between packages:*

```
elev50_crop_spat_rast<-as(elev50_crop, "SpatRaster")
bc_boundary_spat_vect<-as(bc_boundary,"SpatVector")
```

**5.Mask the DEM to the study area**

*Mask the cropped DEM (RUN TIME ~ 1.25 HOURS) using `terra::mask` function within `{tcltk}` progress bar `for` loop. Using `{terra}` because my machine did not have enough memory to run `raster::mask` on ~1.7GB cropped DEM for BC*

*Set up conditions for separate progress bar window (progress bar is optional):*

```
n_iter <- 50 # Number of iterations
pb <- tkProgressBar(title = "Tk progress bar",      # window title
                    label = "Percentage completed", # window label
                    min = 0,      # minimum value of the bar
                    max = n_iter, # maximum value of the bar
                    initial = 0,  # initial value of the bar
                    width = 300)  # width of the window
```

*Progress bar `for` loop:*

```
for(i in 1:n_iter) {
  
  #(CAN BE RUN WITHOUT PROGRESS BAR FOR LOOP) raster mask function
  #mask the DEM to the study area
  bc_dem<-terra::mask(elev50_crop_spat_rast,bc_boundary_spat_vect)
  pctg <- paste(round(i/n_iter *100, 0), "% completed")
  setTkProgressBar(pb, i, label = pctg)
}
```

*Close the connection after progress bar shows 100%:*

```
close(pb)
```

*Convert masked DEM from a `{terra}` compatible raster back to a normal raster:*

```
bc_dem_rast<-raster(bc_dem)
```

*Write masked elevation raster as tif:*

```
raster::writeRaster(bc_dem_rast,filename=file.path(here,paste("bc_dem_50m_mask",sep="")), format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)
```

**6.(OPTIONAL) interactive mapping of the DEM using `{tmap}`**

*(OPTIONAL) memory limit may need to be increased for some commands to run on large files. Try running without this first:*

```
memory.limit(size=60000)
memory.limit()
```

*Toggle `{tmap}` between static and interactive modes:*

```
tmap_mode('plot')
tmap_mode('view')
```

*Increase the number of pixels `{tmap}` will display. 1x10^7 seemed to be the max for this version:*

```
tmap_options("max.raster")
tmap_options(max.raster = c(plot = 1e+7,view = 1e+7))
```

*Use `{stars}` instead of `{raster}` to read in the DEM. `{stars}` seemed to work better than `{raster}` on the large file sizes:*

```
dem<-stars::read_stars(file.path(here,"bc_dem_50m_mask.tif"))
```

*Call an interactive `{tmap}` for a greyscale DEM for BC. Scale is set for 0-2321 m.a.s.l. with breaks every 100m:*

```
tm_shape(dem)+
  tm_raster(midpoint=NA,
            palette="-Greys",
            style = "fixed",
            breaks=seq(0,2321,by=100))
```

*Below is a screenshot of an interactive version of the DEM that I made with `{tmap}`. The above steps will create output very similar to this:*
[image: Example interactive tmap for 50m DEM for BC]